# Why does adding 1 to all values of this dataset change the result of Chi-square distribution test?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, exponential-distribution

I tested the hypothesis that a dataset (**below**) follow the exponential distribution by using the following Matlab command:

```
[h] = chi2gof(dataset,'CDF', fitdist(dataset,'Exponential'), 'Alpha',0.01 );
```

and the result was:

```
h = 0
```

Which means that the test failed to reject the null hypothesis. However, when I add `1` to all the values of this dataset (i.e. `dataset=dataset+1;`) and re-run the test, the test does reject the null hypothesis this time!

**I do not understand why would adding 1 have this effect**, and I would deeply appreciate an explanation.

**Here is my dataset:**

```
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
8
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
3
0
1
0
0
2
1
0
1
2
1
0
0
0
0
1
2
1
0
0
3
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
2
0
0
1
3
2
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
3
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
2
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
3
2
1
0
1
0
1
0
3
0
5
2
5
7
3
6
5
4
1
2
5
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
2
9
0
3
6
2
1
4
3
4
3
2
6
6
2
3
3
4
3
1
4
1
1
1
2
3
3
4
4
4
2
2
2
2
2
4
4
2
2
2
2
2
4
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
2
1
0
3
0
11
2
1
12
8
0
2
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
4
6
3
0
7
3
3
9
5
1
0
9
4
4
0
35
0
3
1
6
0
5
3
6
3
1
1
1
3
1
1
1
1
1
3
3
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
38
0
1
0
35
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
2
0
1
3
2
0
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
2
1
1
3
1
0
5
3
3
2
2
1
1
1
1
2
3
2
1
8
5
3
2
3
7
7
4
4
4
5
0
1
2
2
4
11
6
4
5
4
2
9
11
0
0
0
3
3
2
0
3
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
4
2
1
2
0
0
2
10
1
0
0
4
0
0
3
8
0
1
6
3
2
1
0
0
0
0
2
1
1
3
0
0
0
5
0
2
0
0
0
0
4
5
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
3
1
1
0
1
0
2
2
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
2
1
2
1
1
0
1
5
4
3
5
1
1
4
0
2
1
0
0
1
0
1
1
7
0
0
1
2
1
2
1
2
0
0
1
5
0
0
0
3
0
1
1
1
10
4
7
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
2
0
2
0
2
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
2
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
6
4
0
2
0
0
5
5
1
8
1
2
0
2
0
1
2
0
0
0
0
1
2
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
3
3
1
3
3
3
1
3
1
3
1
1
1
2
2
3
1
0
1
1
3
1
1
1
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
3
0
0
0
0
0
4
10
1
3
1
2
1
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
2
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
3
0
1
0
0
0
4
1
0
0
0
2
0
3
1
1
1
2
3
0
0
1
3
1
2
1
3
2
2
2
2
3
2
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
2
2
2
3
2
1
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
2
3
2
3
3
3
3
2
2
3
3
3
2
1
3
2
2
0
0
1
1
3
3
3
3
1
3
3
3
3
2
1
1
2
3
2
0
4
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
2
4
4
4
4
2
2
2
3
1
1
0
0
1
1
2
4
4
3
5
5
1
2
2
4
7
3
1
0
4
2
2
4
1
1
1
4
1
3
2
2
3
0
0
1
2
2
10
1
10
0
3
2
4
1
1
2
1
0
1
3
7
4
2
3
0
1
4
5
5
2
5
3
0
1
3
3
2
3
3
7
1
5
1
1
0
2
1
0
4
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
2
0
0
10
2
1
0
0
2
0
0
0
1
2
1
1
0
0
0
2
0
1
1
0
1
1
2
5
1
2
8
3
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
4
7
0
3
2
2
3
2
2
0
2
4
3
4
3
3
3
0
1
2
1
3
8
3
1
0
0
1
4
1
0
0
1
0
1
5
1
3
4
5
5
6
4
4
1
0
4
6
3
0
4
7
2
3
0
0
0
1
4
3
3
3
2
3
4
2
7
2
0
2
6
0
0
0
1
1
6
2
3
3
2
2
5
3
3
4
2
0
2
2
2
2
4
2
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
3
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
0
0
1
2
3
3
1
0
1
1
2
0
0
1
2
1
2
4
6
1
0
3
1
1
12
1
3
0
4
2
0
2
0
0
0
1
0
3
15
6
1
0
0
0
2
2
2
0
5
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
3
2
1
1
2
1
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
3
2
0
0
0
0
0
2
5
4
7
7
2
2
1
3
0
1
4
4
0
6
1
5
3
0
3
1
2
0
1
0
0
1
2
0
0
0
5
1
3
2
1
4
1
4
0
6
1
3
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
7
2
0
1
0
1
5
4
2
3
5
2
2
0
0
5
3
3
1
4
0
0
3
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
6
3
0
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
0
2
0
3
7
2
5
5
5
2
2
2
2
3
4
4
4
2
15
5
1
2
6
2
2
4
5
2
2
3
3
3
1
2
3
2
2
1
2
3
3
2
5
2
2
4
2
4
4
2
2
2
6
6
2
2
2
4
4
2
2
2
2
5
5
6
6
6
3
1
5
4
4
4
4
4
4
3
4
4
4
4
4
2
1
2
2
3
2
1
1
2
2
2
8
4
2
1
0
1
2
2
4
4
3
1
2
3
7
1
1
3
2
0
3
3
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
7
3
2
2
2
2
2
2
5
5
1
1
2
4
2
3
3
1
2
2
2
2
1
3
3
2
1
1
2
1
2
2
5
2
4
2
5
2
4
3
1
3
4
3
2
2
3
4
5
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
2
6
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
4
3
1
2
3
2
2
2
2
1
2
3
4
4
3
4
3
3
6
5
4
3
4
2
3
2
3
2
3
3
3
2
3
2
5
6
3
5
3
3
2
3
3
5
1
3
3
4
2
4
4
3
3
4
3
2
3
4
3
3
2
3
2
3
3
3
2
2
2
4
4
4
2
3
4
2
2
2
1
2
2
4
2
8
4
1
2
3
2
8
2
2
1
2
1
2
3
3
9
4
5
3
8
5
2
1
2
2
2
5
3
2
3
2
3
3
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
2
3
3
2
3
2
3
2
2
2
2
5
2
2
1
3
3
2
2
2
3
2
2
3
2
2
6
5
3
2
2
3
7
2
2
2
3
2
3
2
2
3
2
2
3
2
3
2
3
4
7
5
2
2
3
2
2
2
7
3
9
2
3
2
7
5
6
2
0
0
4
3
2
1
2
2
2
3
3
5
2
3
2
1
1
1
1
7
1
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
6
1
2
5
3
6
2
5
5
4
6
0
2
2
2
4
0
5
0
0
0
1
2
4
1
5
0
0
1
3
2
2
2
2
0
3
2
5
5
2
2
2
5
4
2
0
1
3
1
2
2
2
5
2
0
0
1
0
2
0
2
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
```

**UPDATE:**

Following the suggestion of @whuber, I have fitted and plotted a density function on the histogram of the dataset, before and after adding `1`. The results are shown in the image below.

The distribution of the dataset does look closer to the density function before adding `1`, which I assume is the answer to my question.

[image: Dataset before and after adding 1]

Comment: Why not plot the density functions of some exponential distributions and compare them to histograms of your data?  You will immediately see why your approach is problematic.

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much. I think I do see now why it is problematic. If you can add an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: 1. Your data are discrete (the sample values are small integers). You shouldn't be fitting a continuous distribution, but a discrete one (like a geometric, say, which fits the lowest 99.7% of the data quite well ... the three large values  --- 35,35,38 -- aren't really consistent with it though; you would expect to see values that large only very rarely). Your histograms are unhelpful; they have too few bins to see what's happening at the low end.

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for your helpful comment. I thought that it is OK to fit a discrete variable using a continuous distribution, but not the other way around. Is this wrong or just not recommended?

Comment: It can be okay to go either way in some particular situations -- it depends on the circumstances. If the discrete values are small integers, a continuous distribution will tend to be quite poor for most purposes. However, a suitably-discretized continuous distribution may sometimes be adequate. In the case of taking the integer part of an exponential, you should get a geometric distribution; but in that case you might as well just start with the geometric...

Answer (score 3):

Testing whether a data-set follows the exponential distribution is based on the relative number of samples in each category. Adding 1 sample to every category changes the relative sizes of the categories. So it potentially also changes how much your distribution looks like an exponential distribution.

Maybe a more intuitive example. Consider testing whether your samples are uniformly distributed over the categories. If you keep adding a single sample to each category for long enough, any dataset starts looking like it is uniformly distributed.

Comment: Thanks, but the number of samples is not changed. I only add `1` to each existing memeber of the dataset.